# How to choose among two classes given a condition in c++?

Tags: c++

Suppose there are two classes Class1 and Class2. given a condition I have to choose among them in shortest way possible without using if-else.
Means least lines of code.
At compile time only!!!

```
class class1{};
class class2{};

auto data = (((condition) ? class1 : class2) *)(variable)
```

Comment: Compile time? Run time? What do you mean by "choosing" - what will you do after the "choice"? Create an object of that type? Call a member function?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, please clarify

Comment: Please show us some *actual* code that demonstrates the exact problem you're trying to solve. Right now the question is much too vague to be answerable.

Comment: I tried doing something like above.

Comment: But it is not working. I have to choose among the classes in smallest way possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need to create object at *compile time* depending on a variable, you can try something like following

```
class class1{};
class class2{};

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    constexpr bool variable =true;

    /* x is object of type class1 or class2 depending on 
       compile time constant 'variable'
    */

    typedef std::conditional<variable, class1, class2>::type x;


    //std::cout << typeid(x).name() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

See [`Here`](http://rextester.com/RSF92712)

Comment: thank you. it might work